# Dynamically build a table with PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I've been reading some q&a but still haven't managed to build my algorithm, so I'm asking for some help/suggestions on how to.

So, I have a MySQL table and for each mysql table row I want to display it in a table. I want my table to have only 4 cols (meaning the number of rows is variable depending on the data in the database). So, in html table's (row 1, col 1) would be the data from db table row 1, html (row 1, col 2) data from db table row 2 ... (row 2, col 1) data from db table row 5 and so on.

So, the table would be something like:

> [data from db row #1] [data from db row #2] [data from db row #3] [data from db row #4]
>
> [data from db row #5] [data from db row #6] [data from db row #7] [data from db row #8]
>
> and so on...

This is what I have to get the data from db:

```
function get_albums() {
    $albums = array();
    
    $albums_query = mysql_query("SELECT 'albums'.'album_id', 'albums'.'role_id', 'albums'.'timestamp', 'albums'.'name', LEFT('albums'.'description',50) as 'description', COUNT('images'.'image_id') as 'image_count'
    FROM 'albums'
    LEFT JOIN 'images'
    ON 'albums'.'album_id' = 'images'.'album_id'
    GROUP BY 'albums'.'album_id'");
        
    // Loop through all images
    while ($albums_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($albums_query)) {
        // multidimensional array
        $albums[] = array(
                    // associative array
                    'id' => $albums_row['album_id'],
                    'role' => $albums_row['role_id'],
                    'timestamp' => $albums_row['timestamp'],
                    'name' => $albums_row['name'],
                    'description' => $albums_row['description'],
                    'image_count' => $albums_row['image_count']
        );
    }   
    return $albums;
}
```

To display that info:

```
$albums = get_albums();

echo '<table>';
for ($i=0; $i<(count($albums)/4); $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';

    //HERE IS WHERE I'M LOST

    foreach ($albums as $album) {
        echo '<a href="view_album.php?aid=',$album['id'],'">',$album['name'],'</a> (',$album['image_count'],') image(s)<br />',$album['description'],'...';

    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

So, any ideas?

Comment: You're forgetting your `<td>` tags and concatenating with `,` instead of `.`.

Comment: You'll want to use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) and remove the division by 4 in the for loop. And +1 to what Matt said.

Comment: Firstly, your concatting in your query is not correct. Secondly, you're selecting multiple columns per data entry, but you want to display all of it as one cell? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: I 'forgot' the <td> tags on purpose because it's where I don't know what to code.

Comment: Palladium, nop, I want each database row per table cell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// keep calculations outside of the for loop if you can

// this will display all albums (count($albums) / 4) times.

$limit = count($albums) / 4;
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($albums as $album) {
        echo '<td><a href="view_album.php?aid=' . 
            $album['id'] . '">' . $album['name'] . '</a> (' . 
            $album['image_count'] . ') image(s)<br />' . 
            $album['description'] . '...</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

What you're probably looking for is

```
<?php
$counter = 0;

foreach($albums as $album) :
    // start new row 
    if ($counter == 0): ?>
        <tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td><a href="view_album.php?aid=<?= $album['id'] ?>"><?= $album['name'] ?></a> (<?= $album['image_count'] ?>) image(s)<br />         
        <?= $album['description'] ?>...</td>
    <?php if ($counter++ == 3) : ?> <!-- 4 records printed in row; end row & reset counter -->
        </tr>
    <?php
        $counter = 0;
    endif;
endforeach;

$lastCount = $counter;
// print remaining empty cells
while ($counter ++ < 4) : ?>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
endwhile;
// close row if necessary
if ($lastCount != 3) :
    </tr>
endif;
```

Comment: This isn't quite right. This will output as many `<td>` as there are albums in each row and have as many rows as 25% of the albums.

Comment: @Josh I just noticed that and edited for completeness & clarity. Thx!

Comment: Your update will create 1 album per row, as opposed to the OP's aim, which is 4 albums per row.

Comment: +1 I haven't tested it, but you may want to use prefix increment (`++$a`), rather than postfix (`$a++`). Otherwise, it seems like it should work.

Comment: I did postfix because I want comparison before incrementation.